# mongodb $match operation in $lookup to compare objectId's not working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to find whether a user is liked a product or not while fetching the products from a collection using $lookup operation to search for  like which is in a likes collection consists of two fields productId(likedProduct) and userID(who liked the product) both productId and userId are of type ObjectId
this is my schema for products

```
const products = new mongoose.Schema({
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
},
images: [{
    type: String
}]
});
```

and likes Schema

```
new Schema({
userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    index: true
},
productId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    index: true,
    ref: 'products'
},
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
}
});
```

I have tried using $lookup operator as

```
const { user } = req;
productsModels.aggregate([
            { $sort: { '_id': -1 } },
            { $limit: 10 },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'likes',
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                'productId': '$_id',
                                'userId':user.id
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    as: 'liked'
                }
            },
        ]);}
```

but it's not giving me the expected result even though the user has liked the product
and I got liked as an empty array!

```
{
created: "2019-08-30T10:46:53.692Z"
images: ["8f3447bb-8bb8-4c5a-acde-bcdc1b729c09"]
liked: []
price: 9
title: "developer"
userId: "5d68fea345353e1748cf7a10"
__v: 0
_id: "5d68fec745353e1748cf7a12"}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: See also [Specify Multiple Join Conditions with `$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) in the `$lookup` pipeline stage documentation. You basically are missing the `$expr` operator for the comparison of `product_id` to the `_id` of the parent document. The `user.id` part is *probably* okay as long as that points to a value which is already an `ObjectId`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const { user } = req;

productsModels.aggregate([
            { $sort: { '_id': -1 } },
            { $limit: 10 },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'likes',
                    let: {productId:"$_id"},
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                $expr:{$eq:['$_id', '$$productId']}},
                                'userId': mongoose.Type.Object(user.id)
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    as: 'liked'
                }
            },
        ]);}
```

In your query two things where missing

1) Converting userid to mongo object id so we used `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`

2) You can't use outer collection field directly in inner pipeline for this you have create temp variable so we used `let` to declare and to match with internal field we need to use `$expr`